# Bootstrap4 columns stacks up rather than lying side by side even though right grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a website using bootstrap4, and I'm trying to put two text boxes side by side. Even though I used the 12 grid system, somehow my columns get stacked top/bottom rather than side by side. Below is my code. As you can see, I used `col-md6` for two `<div>` for each writing, and for the mobile version, I used `col-12` so it can have only one writing/image each line. But somehow, for the laptop screen, it doesn't show side by side. Why is this so? When I inspected the page, it shows a huge orange space which I assumed margin, but setting `margin:0` didn't help. :

```css
.album {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.album img {
    width: 800px;
}

.content {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}

.blogWriting {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    padding: 15px 35px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.dateWriting {
    font-size: 13px;
}
.container {
    width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</style>

<div class="album">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-auto firstContent">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="d">
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 content">
              <div class="blogWriting">
              <p><b>Crown Heights</b> is simply dummy text of
                  the printing and typesetting industry.
                  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
                  dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                  when an unknown printer took a galley
                  of type and scrambled it to make a type
                  specimen book. It has survived not only
                  five centuries, but also the leap into
                  electronic typesetting, remaining
                  essentially unchanged.
              </p>
              <p><b>Bushwick</b> is simply dummy text of
                  the printing and typesetting industry.
                  Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
                  dummy text ever since the 1500s,
                  when an unknown printer took a galley
                  of type and scrambled it to make a type
                  specimen book. It has survived not only
                  five centuries, but also the leap into
                  electronic typesetting, remaining
                  essentially unchanged.
              </p>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 content">
              <div class="dateWriting">
                  <p>October 28th, 2020 <br>
                  By Name </p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want it like this on Laptop screen? https://nimb.ws/BLXuip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it seems Bootstrap is not loading correctly through the CDN because you have a style tag around the link. This style tag needs to be removed.

Second of all you have your container inside of your row. The container needs to be around your row.

```
<!-- Removed style tag here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Added container class around row classes. -->
<div class="album container">

  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-auto firstContent">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="d">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 content">
        <div class="blogWriting">
          <p><b>Crown Heights</b> is simply dummy text of
            the printing and typesetting industry.
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
            dummy text ever since the 1500s,
            when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book. It has survived not only
            five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining
            essentially unchanged.
          </p>
          <p><b>Bushwick</b> is simply dummy text of
            the printing and typesetting industry.
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard
            dummy text ever since the 1500s,
            when an unknown printer took a galley
            of type and scrambled it to make a type
            specimen book. It has survived not only
            five centuries, but also the leap into
            electronic typesetting, remaining
            essentially unchanged.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6 content">
        <div class="dateWriting">
          <p>October 28th, 2020 <br>
            By Name </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.album {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.album img {
  width: 800px;
}

.content {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.blogWriting {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.dateWriting {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.container {
  width: 800px;
}
```